# Line 34: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, secret, guess):
        self.secret = secret
        self.guess = guess
    def getHint(self):
        right=0; wrong=0
        listSecret = list(self.secret)
        listGuess = list(self.guess)
        for i in range(len(listSecret)):
            if listSecret[i] == listGuess[i]:
                right = right + 1
            else:
                wrong = wrong + 1
        return str(right)+ "A" + str(wrong) + "B"
guessG = raw_input("")
secretS = raw_input("")
print Solution(str(guessG), str(secretS)).getHint()
```

When I run the code in pycharm, it works. However, when I submit the code to leetcode, it warns "runtime error", see the picture.

[image]

Comment: it's only 19 lines you see in the picture.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I believe author is curious about this also

Comment: @Lol4t0 Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: No. Just guessing: actual code passed to python is concatenation of code you provided with smth else. You might want to reread some manual on your site

Comment: You can't possibly get that error with that code.

Comment: @Lol4t0 You say the last line?

Comment: @BryanOakley so I'm very confused...

Comment: `secret` and `guess` are passed to `getHint()`. You should not specify them into the signature for `__init__`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini   delete the ,`__init__` block?

Comment: @darkmanno6: delete it and restore `def getHint(self, secret, guess):`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini thx，it works.

Answer (score 1):

### This is a *leetcode* service issue

In contrast to the popular format when communication between the test driver and your program is done with standard IO, this service provide another way.

In the begining you are given a code snippet that states communcation interface implicitly. *You should not change it, i.e change method signatures including constructor signature*. Your input is then passed as arguments to the code snippet method with result expecting to be its method return value.

### How all it works and way strange error is generated

The code you pass in your online editor is enreached with some additional code that generates that behaviour.

To check this idea I've written a program that prints its own code (by modifying given snippet):

```
class Solution(object):
    def getHint(self, secret, guess):
        """
        :type secret: str
        :type guess: str
        :rtype: str
        """
        
import sys        
print sys.argv ## this prints program arguments

## argv[0] is the name of file being executed. Just print it!
with open(sys.argv[0], 'r') as fin:
    print fin.read()
```

The result of execution on the codeleet service was

```
['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1/.cache/prog_joined.py', '-recursion_limit', '8100']
# coding: utf-8
from precompiled.__serializer__ import __Serializer__
from precompiled.__deserializer__ import __Deserializer__
from precompiled.__utils__ import __Utils__
from precompiled.listnode import ListNode
from precompiled.interval import Interval
from precompiled.treenode import TreeNode
from precompiled.treelinknode import TreeLinkNode
from precompiled.undirectedgraphnode import UndirectedGraphNode
from precompiled.randomlistnode import RandomListNode
from precompiled.point import Point
import precompiled.__settings__
import array
import bisect
import collections
import copy
import heapq
import itertools
import math
import operator
import re
import sets
import string

# user submitted code insert below
class Solution(object):
    def getHint(self, secret, guess):
        """
        :type secret: str
        :type guess: str
        :rtype: str
        """
        
import sys        
print sys.argv

with open(sys.argv[0], 'r') as fin:
    print fin.read()
import sys
def _driver():
    SEPARATOR = "\x1b\x09\x1d"
    f = open("user.out", "w", 0)
    lines = __Utils__().read_lines()
    while True:
        try:
            line = lines.next()
            
            param_1 = __Deserializer__().to_string(line)
            line = lines.next()
            param_2 = __Deserializer__().to_string(line)
            
            ret = Solution().getHint(
                param_1, param_2
            )
            out = __Serializer__().serialize(ret)

            print >> f, "%s" % out
            sys.stdout.write(SEPARATOR)
        except StopIteration:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _driver()
```

This shows *the whole* program being executed. As you can note it is a bit expanded version of your own code. The version has the following lines:

```
ret = Solution().getHint(
                    param_1, param_2
                )
```

They are the source of your problem

Comment: I find this answer impossible to understand. Where did you get this "enreached" code from? What does "printed the program code" mean?

Comment: @BryanOakley We are talking here about leetcode service as question states. You execute the first code sample that tries to print to the console file being executed. If you run this on the service specified, you get the code provided in the second sample

Comment: @Lol4t0: ah, ok. You might want to add that little bit of clarification to your answer.